# how to send gridview containing image via email using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a gridview that contain image . I want to email that grid containing image. I have a code that send the gridview via email but the image in gridview are not visible at the receiver email id. The image in gridview are displayed from the database. can anyone help me to send gridview with its formatting via email.

```
public string gridData(GridView gv)
{ 
     StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
     HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
     gv.RenderControl(htw);
     return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: inspect image path in test email using firebug

Comment: http://blog.devexperience.net/en/12/Send_an_Email_in_CSharp_with_Inline_attachments.aspx